# What can be the issue when after installing Lubuntu 18.10 shortcuts for window tiling and other ones don't work?

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys, lxqt

I installed Lubuntu 18.10 on my machine. I was used to clicking Windows + Left/Right to get a split screen with opened windows back on Linux Mint, but it's not working on Lubuntu.

Having searched around a bit I tried to edit config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml, but there is no real reason to do that, cause all the necessary lines to make those shortcuts work are present in the file. Having read the Lubuntu Manual chapter 5.4 I am convinced that these shortcuts should work.

Can anybody help me with this?

[image: The lines that should enable the shortcuts in lxqt-rc.xml]

Thanks.

Comment: I got it working. Apparently, there's a conflict with the windows key, because it opens the menu on it's own as well. To get tiling working again, I edited the shortcut for opening the menu to one that doesn't include Super_L in the 'keybard shortcuts' configurator and rebooted.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this, I went to `Menu > Session settings` and then disabled `Global Keyboard Shortcuts` under `Basic settings` tab.

All the keybindings from lxqt-rc.xml started working after that, including `Super_L + E` for pcmanfm and window tiling shortcuts.