# Configuring Lubuntu 18.10's - lxqt-rc.xml file

Tags: lubuntu, 18.10

I'm in the process of converting a couple of machines over to Lubuntu 18.10 which i'm really enjoying by the way! My only problem that I haven't been able to fix or find any information on myself is setting up keyboard shortcuts that use the "windows" key or the left "super" key. Most keyboards bind that key to W in the lxqt-rc.xml file. Only on my laptop, Acer Swift it isn't working with the W. For example I have the following to snap windows using the shift and directional keys:

```
<keybind key="S-Left">
<keybind key="S-Right">
```

The S = Shift. I'd like to be able to use the window key instead which would look like this W - Right, W - Left. Only when I set it as that nothing happens when I press those keys. If anyone knows which key I should be using or a simple method to find out it would make my day!

Comment: I use the previous version of Lubuntu (before the switch to qt) and the key is indeed W there....

Comment: I don't think Lubuntu is the issue, I think it's my laptops keyboard not having the keys mapped. Odd because pressing the windows key will open the lubuntu menu on the panel. So it definitely works but it's not being recognised as "W" in the xml file.

Comment: See if the comment in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088941/what-can-be-the-issue-when-after-installing-lubuntu-18-10-shortcuts-for-window-t?rq=1 helps. Also: https://www.reddit.com/r/Lubuntu/comments/aab6f4/window_key_shortcuts_broken_in_lxqt_1810/eeq0bgi

Comment: Reading [Fix shortcuts related to Super key](https://phab.lubuntu.me/T154) made my head spin.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, I have Lubuntu 18.10 in a VM and it's distinctly a "work in progress" to put it mildly.

Comment: @DKBose I am not a fan of the switch to qt. To put it mildly.

Answer (score 4):

The “Windows” (W) key bindings in lxqt-rc.xml don’t work because the Windows (Super-L) key is bound to ‘Show Main Menu’ in the Global Actions Manager (i.e. the Shortcuts section of LXQt Settings). The rectify this, modify this binding so that e.g. Shift+Ctrl+M is bound to Show Main Menu.

Comment: Can I access the Global Actions Manager via a config file or `xml` in `Lubuntu`? If I change `Global Actions Manager` is it then possible to use `super_L`?