# Openbox doesn't apply changes made in lxqt-rc.xml

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys, openbox

I've wanted to edit some shortcuts, so I added a keybind to my `~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml`, under `<keyboard>`

```
<keybind key="W-S-q">
      <action name="Close" />
</keybind>
```

Sounds pretty simple, but it doesn't apply the changes after `openbox --reconfigure`, as well as after reboot. XML in the file is not malformed, according to some online checker, so that's not the issue. In fact, I don't see any errors in `journalctl`. Other keybinds I add there also don't seem to work. It's even weirder since I copied it from my old config which worked fine under Manjaro. The only similar thing I found is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122495/configuring-lubuntu-18-10s-lxqt-rc-xml-file) question, but I don't have any keybindings conflicting, so that's not the case. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you read the manual (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html?highlight=keyboard%20shortcuts) as you'll note "*Global-keys will take preference over openbox bindings. If a key is used in Global-keys, it will not work in Openbox keyboard shortcuts*"   You didn't provide release details so I didn't look any further as to any potential clashes.

Comment: @guiverc Well, there are no "key conflicts" of any sort, so I don't think that's the case here.